# How to store groups of booleans in Realm for Android?

Tags: android, realm

Let's say I have a dozen booleans to store for each entity and expect the database to store about up to, at most, a few thousand records on any given Android device. As a fictional example, perhaps a Restaurant object has booleans like wifi, valetParking, sitDown, tippingEncouraged, listedOnYelp, etc. Let's also say I want to be able to easily search by them, so it's simple for a user to find restaurants that offer wifi and do not offer valet parking, for example.

How should these be stored on Realm?

I know this question in general for databases is something people like to argue over--whether to simply use a separate int field for each boolean, whether to have a separate table to implement a many-to-many relationship between the booleans and records, or whether to use each boolean as bitshifted flags and store the combination of flags as a single value?

For Realm specifically, my hunch is that it's easiest/best to just store each boolean separately, as it supports booleans and it seems the other approaches would be more complex than they would otherwise. But I'd love for someone more knowledgeable to say the correct, best supported approach in Realm.

Comment: Realm is super fast, what are your worries? A couple thousand objects is nothing

Comment: Realm does some fancy packing of data so storing a boolean doesn't cost a much space as you might fear. On modern CPUs, unpacking isn't costly since they typical have special instructions for that. Long story short, just use a field for each boolean.

Comment: Perfect @geisshirt, it's great to have the official answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** One field per boolean

```
public class Restaurant extends RealmObject {

    private boolean wifi;
    private boolean listedOnYelp;

    /* getter, setter, etc.*/
}
```

- Easy to implement
- Easy to understand
- RealmQueries based on the booleans are possible

**Option 2:** Flag field

64 booleans per long, the masks go from 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup> to 2<sup>64</sup>

```
public class Restaurant extends RealmObject {

    private long booleanFlags;

    private boolean getFlag(long mask) {
        return (booleanFlags & mask) == mask;
    }

    private void setFlag(long mask, boolean value) {
        if (value) {
            booleanFlags |= mask;
        } else {
            booleanFlags &= ~mask; 
        }
    }

    public boolean hasWifi() {
        return getFlag(1);
    }

    public void setWifi(boolean hasWifi) {
        setFlag(1, hasWifi);
    }

    public boolean isListedOnYelp() {
        return getFlag(2);
    }

    public boolean isTippingEncouraged() {
        return getFlag(4);
    }
}
```

- Super memory efficient (unless Realm does not do the same in its core)
- Not so easy to read or understand
- No RealmQueries based on the booleans

**Option 3:** Extra class

```
public class Restaurant extends RealmObject {
    /*...*/
}

public class RestaurantPropertyStore extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<Restaurant> restaurantsWithWifi;
    private RealmList<Restaurant> restaurantsListedOnYelp;
}
```

- Not object-oriented
- *Queries* on one boolean at a time are possible

---

Option 1 is the object-oriented, Java-like and Realm-like way
Option 2 is the C, C++ way
Option 3 is the SQL, RDBMS way

Comment: I recommend Option 1